# Mirroring private vlan on catalyst switches

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, private-vlan, mirror

I currently have a catalyst switch configured with private VLANs and would like to mirror that traffic to an external system. I have tried creating a monitor session for the VLANs involved but that does not seem to help since I dont see any unicast traffic.
Has anyone done this before?
The issue is also that the firewall is a module in the same switch and hence I cannot mirror the port going to a firewall either. But perhaps there are other solutions to this?

Cheers.